# Pipeline success but no email notification

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I have pipeline that when its success to build, it will send out email notification. The last its success to send out email notification was 17/1/2024. After we do not receive any email notification.

I have check Manage Jenkins>System>Extended E-mail Notification and there are no changes been done.

Can help to advice. Thank you

Comment: You can track the logs by going to `Manage Jenkins>System Log`, Add a new log recorder by clicking on `Add Record button`, give it a name and select recorder, in your case select `hudson.plugins.emailext` as recorder, See if it gives appropriate logs.